# How to remove the single quotes from the request header in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, http-headers, request-promise

Basically, I have a simple header object.

```
let headers = {
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "upgrade-insecure-requests": 1
}
```

When I send a request with this as the header object with `request-promise` on node js it times out to the web url.

When I send the raw headers, without the quotes included in a rest postman type client,

```
GET to /url
pragma: no-cache
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
```

The request misses and continues, caseless. This may be something really stupid but I cannot figure out what is going on here.

I cannot replicate the the rest response in node and need to remove the single or double quote from the actual header object key, or the request will timeout.

You cannot edit the object with `headers[upgrade-insecure-requests]` because there is dashes included.

Comment: Is `no-cache` supposed to be a string? That might be the problem. Having the quotes around your keys in a JS object is not the problem. You should show more code as well since it's difficult to know what you're doing with no code available. How are you sending the data, what library if any? Make sure to provide anything useful.

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning that if your objects key has dashes or spaces or anything you can access it with `header['upgrade-insecure-requests']` notice the quotes inside the square bracket. Same goes for a situation where you need to add a key that includes spaces/dashes or anything. `header['my new-header'] = 'foo'` is still valid.

Comment: I am aware of how to access object keys. The problem is related to the fact that i need to remove the actual quotes. Edited, since no-cache is a string, but thats not the problem, the problem is that the header object keys are being enveloped in the request.

Comment: I know this because when I add the quotes to a normal rest client headers request, it also times out.

Comment: I don't think quotes are your problem. I think something else is wrong. The server is timing out, and it should not do that. Perhaps you need to log the error from the server in order to see what's wrong, or investigate the server's logs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure you need to remove any quotes

I think something else could be wrong

In fact, it's possible you need to ***add*** some quotes, such that all of the header values are in fact strings

```
const headers = {
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
}
```

Let me know if "wrapping the integer `1` in double quotes to make it a string" works or not :)